# The values are being appended instead of being calculated

Tags: jquery

When i click on the plus icon ,

from the second click onwards , the price is being , the quantity and the price are being calculated wrongly

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function(event)
{
    var idval = $(this).parents('.lastItm_Wrap').first().attr('id');
  var currentval = $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr('value');
  if (currentval === '')
  {
    currentval = 0;
  }
  var currentQuantity = parseInt(currentval + 1);
  if (currentQuantity == 0)
  {
    currentQuantity = 1;
  }
  var currentSellprice = parseFloat($("#" + idval).find('.prd_title h3').data('sellprice'));
  $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text(parseFloat(currentSellprice * currentQuantity).toFixed(2));

  $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr('value', currentQuantity);
  $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(currentQuantity);
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/8/

Comment: Sorry for troubling you , adding else condition  with parseInt,  else
    {
        currentval = parseInt(currentval);
    } has resolved the issue .

Comment: fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/9/

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate `currentQuantity` you conctenate two strings("1" and "1", "11" and "1" etc.). Change you code to this.

```
var currentQuantity = parseInt(currentval) + 1;
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the +1 outside the parseInt otherwise it parses 1+1 as string... that will be 11 :)

see http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/10/

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function(event)
{
    var idval = $(this).parents('.lastItm_Wrap').first().attr('id');
  var currentval = $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr('value');
  if (currentval === '')
  {
    currentval = 0;
  }
  var currentQuantity = parseInt(currentval)+ 1;
  if (currentQuantity == 0)
  {
    currentQuantity = 1;
  }
  var currentSellprice = parseFloat($("#" + idval).find('.prd_title h3').data('sellprice'));
  $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text(parseFloat(currentSellprice * currentQuantity).toFixed(2));

  $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').attr('value', currentQuantity);
  $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(currentQuantity);
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```